# Can I play Blizzard games without my friends knowing I'm online?

Tags: battle.net

Sometimes I want to play games without other people bugging me. In the Steam client it possible to appear offline to your friends while playing. Does the Blizzard game client offer this same functionality?

If not, is it possible to just hide the fact that I am in a game from my status?

Comment: Some games can be launched without the launcher (I am sure it's possible with WoW, don't know of others).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not implemented yet, apparently [Blizzard has plans to implement it "soon"](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7315730/appear-offline-option-coming-soon-to-battlenet-9-20-2012), which is likely to be sometime between now and the end of times (i.e Soon ™). Especially since this post is already over three years old.

I"ve also been wishing for this simple functionality for years...

Answer (score -5):

I mentioned all of this in a post on the Battle.net forums and lots of people apparently hated me for it, so don't get hung up if you don't like it. These are just suggestions for how to get around the problem until Blizzard implements something.

1. Why you want to appear offline is very important to whether a suggestion is useful. Some people have some psychological need to be "invisible" that apparently can't be satisfied unless literally nobody can tell they're online. I can't help those people except suggest a psychiatrist if it's bothering you to the point it affects your life, or to play a different game while it's bothering you.

   Other people just don't like dealing with people sometimes. That's a simpler problem and you have the tools to deal with it now.
2. Turn off your chat pane. In WoW, you can set it to the combat log or pet battle log, etc. and just ignore any tabs with people talking to you. There are probably addons to completely turn off any incoming messages then turn them on later, but I'm not sure (you can do it manually, but that's a pain).

   In D3, you can just leave all your public chat channels, although I'm not sure it's possible to ignore incoming B.Net messages. Still, you can switch to the "party" channel and not see messages. You can also turn off B.Net notifications from the Options -> Social pane. You'll also want to disable Quick Join functionality.
3. Now, you can set your b.tag/RID status to "Busy", which tells your friends to leave you alone. In WoW, I know you can /afk "Some message" so if they whisper you it will re-whisper them with your message like "Just doing my own thing right now, not in the mood for people. Talk to you later." so they know it's a you thing not a them thing.

   I'm not sure if you can put a message like that directly for your B.Net Busy status, but you can set a general "shout out" message. Everyone will see it, not just people who try to whisper you first. From what I can tell there's no /afk command in D3 like WoW and D2.
4. Next is a social thing. You just need to let people know that your alone time is important to you, and "Busy" means everyone. Some of the B.net forum posters said people just keeping bugging them, but I've never had an issue with it in any of my guilds. The only reason it should ever bother someone else that you're not in the mood to socialize is if you promised to be there.

   Realistically you don't *need* to bother with this step. It should be pretty obvious to people that when your Busy flag is set you ignore them. 2+2=stop bothering this guy. But some people don't get the hint, and telling them outright could help.
5. Ok, so you're one of those unlucky people who keep getting bugged and you can't figure out a way to block some particular messages from getting through. That's what the ignore feature is for. I'd guess there's a WoW addon for quickly toggling the ignore status on problem people, but I haven't looked. As far as I'm concerned, anyone who can't figure out that you really want them to leave you alone probably isn't worth taking back off ignore, but that's your call to make.

Some of those solutions are WoW-specific, and you appear to be playing D3. A WoW addon doesn't help you much unless you also have a paid WoW account. Then you *could* log into WoW, use your WoW addon to toggle everything, then hop over to D3. Repeat when you're unbusy. But you can't access B.Net with a F2P account so that won't work if you don't play WoW, and is a bit cumbersome.

You can still do everything, you just can't click a button to /ignore a dozen people at once. Literally all of my Blizzard games require an update right now, so I can't test anything more specific for D3, SC2, HS or HotS. And my internet is slow so it will probably be a few hours.

I believe SC2 can be played in campaign mode offline, but it's been a while since I bothered. I know D3 requires a connection, so you're stuck there.

Comment: None of those makes one appear 'offline', so it's not an answer. And -1 for "I can't help those people except suggest a psychiatrist."

Comment: The question asked how to not be bothered. That's what I answered. And please read the entire statement before -1-ing me. If something about a video game is so horrible it's affecting your life, it's time to get professional help.

Comment: There are two question marks in the question (three if you count the title). None of those sentences ending in a question mark is about how not to be bothered; All are about how to appear offline.

Comment: The problem is stated as: "Sometimes I want to play games without other people bugging me." You don't have to appear offline to solve that problem unless you define "people bugging me" as "I know they can tell I'm online even though they can't talk to me or anything". Some people use that definition. I can't help them. Most people don't. This answer is for them.

Comment: You are ignoring all the other sentences, cherry-picking one line instead. Are you a politician by any chance? My -1 stands.

Comment: No, I'm an engineer. We solve problems. The first step to solving a problem is to cut through all the irrelevant stuff, like "I want to be invisible", and get to the problem statement itself. Here, the querent's problem is explicitly stated that they want to be left alone. You don't need to be invisible to be left alone, that's just one (currently im-) possible solution. My answer involves solutions that are currently available to the querent for the actual problem stated by the querent.

Comment: In other words, you're an engineer that gives workarounds instead of actual solutions. Also, you did *not* answer the actual question of wanting to appear offline (which is the -title-). The author then describes why he wants the feature (wants left alone) which is what you proceeded to answer, even though this in effect does not give the user the ability to appear offline and actually be left alone. Steam offers the ability to go offline and still play your favorite games, so it's really a question of why is Blizz so lazy that they can't add something so simple to their chat client.

Comment: @Lo-Tan: Just because it's not an ideal solution doesn't make it something other than a solution. While Blizzard could and probably should add a simpler way to do this, it's irrelevant to the question of what can be done now. Instead of crying about it like most of the other answers, I gave potential solutions that have helped many people with the actual problem, which for most people has nothing to do with appearing offline and everything to do with not being bothered by others.

Comment: And the title of the question doesn't seem to be the real question at all. It's the user's attempt at a solution to the actual problem which is stated in the question. See [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: "suggest a psychiatrist", yes you really thought that one through... Look sometimes people like having a little privacy. We aren't talking about messages just privacy in general. If you can't understand that then I suggest a psychiatrist.

Comment: @Petro: I did think it through. You just didn't bother to read what I wrote. There's a little thing called [context](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/context).